# setOnItemClickListener error in ListView wth ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

i'm developing android app, which requires **listview** with **ArrayAdapter**. now i want **onItemClickListener** on this listview. but the IDE, Anacode(same as eclipse), shows an error for it!

I have tried every answers in posts of questions like this. but no help!

Please help

```
//the code 
package edward.harsh.friends;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;   

public class ListViewSampleActivity extends Activity
{
    ListView mCountriesLV;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /**
         * Get the control instances from the main.xml layout
         */
        mCountriesLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesLV);
        mCountriesLV.setAdapter(new CountriesAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_country_row, mCountriesList));



        mCountriesLV.setOnItemClickListener(
          new OnItemClickListener() 
          {
                   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
           });

   }
}
```

error message is

```
   The method    setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in the type
  AdapterView <ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new   OnItemClickListener(){})

OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

as suggested by some.  I even tried this

```
  mCountriesLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
          {
                   @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
           });
```

but it throws another error

```
The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView <?>, View, int, long)
```

Comment: Please add to your question where and what the error is...

Comment: why is there an iframe tag?

Comment: probably your there are some onClickListeners in your CountriesAdapter.class. Remove them

Comment: @Dan I edited the question

Comment: @manoj.  iframe was just for posting this code in here

Comment: It seems you have imported the wrong OnItemClickListener, try this one instead, and remove import of android.view.View.OnClickListener

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Comment: @kostya there is no onClickListener there

Comment: I have imported  android.widget.*; and android.view*; @HsRaja

Comment: it's directly in front of it @Mike

Comment: it's there I first blockof code

Comment: Please try adding, import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()** in *setOnItemClickListener* method, its not applicable for only *OnItemClickListener*

```
mCountriesLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: plz update your listview in question whatever you have written

Comment: list view as in?  countriesAdapter.java or the XML file?

Comment: update ListViewSampleActivity file with new code whatever you have written

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead

```
mCountriesLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {}
```

Your Listener should be AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: what is another erro

Comment: I just added  it in questions.. just look ^

Comment: can you post your imports

Comment: just remove your import you will get error and add import by selecting the error word and press alt+enter in windows or option + enter in mac let android studio decide which class they want to import. There are many such class with same name but different package which causes ambiguous issue

Comment: well I'm doing it on android phone so now what?

Comment: i am telling you about IDE where your coding

Comment: the IDE I'm using have no any feature like that

Comment: which IDE you are usin

Comment: import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

Comment: I'm using  Anacode in android.   and I imported  whole view and widget by wild card